# JQuery задача / Присвоить курсору положение объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно чтобы курсор или псевдо-курсор (элемент div например) анимацией принимал позицию инпута, каким образом это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Координаты мыши относительно элемента

```
<input onmousemove="this.value = event.clientX+':'+event.clientY">
```

Координаты мыши относительно страницы

```
<input onmousemove="this.value = event.pageX+':'+event.pageY">
```